# Mirror index into array

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have and array of size n. Now when get an index i which can be in the range of [-n; 2n-1] I want to index into the array as follows

[image]
The arrows indicate which element should be returned if i goes below 0(yellow) or above n - 1(blue)

Comment: Is the array size always 5? Do you always mirror it into a 15 item array?

Comment: no, the array size is arbitrary, but it's given

Comment: Is the mirror always 3x the array size then?

Comment: yes if the size is n the range is [-n; 2n-1]

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *"any smart way"*. You can certainly do it with a couple of `if` statements.

Comment: i am using this in order to index into a 2D image (one time for the x axis and one time for the y axis). So depending on the image size I don't want to call a couple of if statements for every pixel.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose your array of possible values is of length n (in our case [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] has a length of 5). The whole length of the mirror will be of length 2n - 1:

```
possibleValues = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now, assuming that the value array at index 0 has the middle of the mirror (0), you have to work with modular arithmetic, with the formula of

```
result[v] = possibleValues[((v + n - 1) % 2n - 1)]
```

now, since your actual array looks like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], you need to convert that index used at possible values to something which is more helpful for your actual array:

```
possibleIndex = ((v + n - 1) % 2n - 1)
if (possibleIndex >= n) actualIndex = possibleIndex - n + 1
else possibleIndex = actualIndex = n = possibleIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using spread operator and reverse array method

```js
var arrOne = [0,1,2,3,4];
var result = []
var revArr = [...arrOne].reverse()
result = [...revArr,...arrOne, ...revArr]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mirrorArr(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    newArr.length = arr.length * 3;

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr[-arr[i]-1] = arr[i];
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
        newArr[i+arr.length] = arr.length-i-1;
    }
    return newArr;
}
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
let mirroredArr = mirrorArr(arr);
console.log(mirroredArr[-5]);
```

something like this does the trick